# Table not sorting or filtering correctly

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

**Repairtable.php**

```
    <?php

// Connect to the database
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'repair_shop');
if ($db->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
}

// Get the search input from the form
$search = isset($_GET['search']) ? $_GET['search'] : '';

// Get the sorting parameters from the query string
$sort = isset($_GET['sort']) && !empty($_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : 'work_orders.id';
$order = isset($_GET['order']) && in_array($_GET['order'], array('asc', 'desc')) ? $_GET['order'] : 'asc';
$status = isset($_GET['status']) && !empty($_GET['status']) ? $_GET['status'] : '';




$where = "WHERE customers.name LIKE '%$search%' OR devices.type LIKE '%$search%' OR devices.issues LIKE '%$search%'";
if ($status) {
  $where .= " AND work_orders.status='$status'";
} else {
  $where .= " AND work_orders.status IN ('Awaiting Repair', 'Repair In Progress', 'Ready For Pickup', 'Repair Complete', 'Sale Complete')";
}


$query = "SELECT work_orders.id, devices.type AS device_name, customers.name, work_orders.status, devices.service_request_id, devices.issues
          FROM work_orders
          INNER JOIN devices ON work_orders.device_id = devices.id
          INNER JOIN customers ON devices.customer_id = customers.id
          $where
          ORDER BY work_orders.status $order
          LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0";


echo("status: " . $status);



$result = $db->query($query);

// Check for errors
if ($db->error) {
  die("Query failed: " . $conn->error);
}

// Check if there are any results
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {?>
<table class='table table-striped'>
<tr class='thead-dark'>
  <th>
    <a href="#" onclick="loadRepairs('id', '<?php echo !empty($sort) && !empty($order) ? ($sort == 'id' && $order == 'asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc' : ''; ?>'); return false;">ID</a>
  </th>
  <th>
    <a href="#" onclick="loadRepairs('device_name', '<?php echo !empty($sort) && !empty($order) ? ($sort == 'device_name' && $order == 'asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc' : ''; ?>'); return false;">Device Name</a>
  </th>
  <th>
    <a href="#" onclick="loadRepairs('name', '<?php echo !empty($sort) && !empty($order) ? ($sort == 'name' && $order == 'asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc' : ''; ?>'); return false;">Customer Name</a>
  </th>
  <th>
<form method="get" id="form" action="#">
  <select id="status" name="status" onchange="loadRepairs('<?php echo $sort; ?>', '<?php echo $order; ?>');">
        <option value="">Status</option>
        <option value='Awaiting Repair'>Awaiting Repair</option>
        <option value='Repair In Progress'>Repair In Progress</option>
        <option value='Ready For Pickup'>Ready For Pickup</option>
        <option value='Repair Complete'>Repair Complete</option>
        <option value='Sale Complete'>Sale Complete</option>
      </select>
    </form>
      </th>
      <th>
  <a href="#" onclick="loadRepairs('service_request_id', '<?php echo !empty($sort) && !empty($order) ? ($sort == 'service_request_id' && $order == 'asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc' : ''; ?>'); return false;">Service Request ID</a>
</th>

      <th>issues</th>
      <th>View/Edit</th>
    </tr>
  <?php
  

  // Print the table rows
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td class='align-middle'>" . htmlspecialchars($row['id']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='align-middle'>" . htmlspecialchars($row['device_name']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='align-middle'>" . htmlspecialchars($row['name']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='align-middle'>" . htmlspecialchars($row['status']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='align-middle'>" . htmlspecialchars($row['service_request_id']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='align-middle'>" . htmlspecialchars($row['issues']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='align-middle'><button class='btn btn-primary' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#repairModal' data-id='" . $row['id'] . "' data-device-name='" . $row['device_name'] . "' data-customer-name='" . $row['name'] . "' data-service-request-id='" . $row['service_request_id'] . "' data-status='" . $row['status'] . "' data-issues='" . $row['issues'] . "'>View/Edit</button></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }
  // Close the table
  ?>
  
  </table>
  <?php
// Close the database connection
$db->close();
}
?>
```

**LoadRepairs function:**

```
      function loadRepairs(sort = 'id', order = 'asc') {
    // Get the selected status value
    var status = $('#status').val();
    console.log(status);
    // Load the repairtable.php file into the repairsTable element,
    // and include the selected status value, as well as the sort and order values,
    // in the query string
    $.get(`includes/repairtable.php?status=${status}&sort=${sort}&order=${order}`, function(response) {
      $('#repairsTable').html(response);
    });
  }
```

**Query with a status selected:**

```
SELECT work_orders.id, devices.type AS device_name, customers.name, work_orders.status, devices.service_request_id, devices.issues FROM work_orders INNER JOIN devices ON work_orders.device_id = devices.id INNER JOIN customers ON devices.customer_id = customers.id WHERE customers.name LIKE '%%' OR devices.type LIKE '%%' OR devices.issues LIKE '%%' AND work_orders.status='Awaiting Repair' ORDER BY work_orders.status asc LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

So, this produces a table with headers which are links to sort the table, except for status, it's a dropdown for filtering the table to only display the selected status.

The trouble is that none of the sorting and filtering seems to work as expected. when i click a table header, it will sort by ascending or descending, but it sometimes has random mixed in results which are not in the desired order, like 21 appearing before 20, additionally when i filter the results with the status dropdown, it just doesn't filter at all.

My guess is that my sql query is poorly constructed, because that's my weakest area, but i'm really just not sure anymore. i've debugged seemingly each link in the chain, but i can't seem to find the bug. I'm really hoping someone else can.

If any more detail is required, please let me know. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks to everyone warning me about SQL injection, You guys are 100% right, but i'm also designing this to be used by a grand total of 3 people, all of which are employees of the store for which i work, so i'm not super worried about attack vectors, but thank you for looking out for me. The sentiment is appreciated.

Comment: To debug this, you could echo out the query string you're generating, then just show the query and the results.  It's likely you'll see the problem at that point, but if you don't, it will greatly reduce the amount of effort needed to help solve your problem.  (We don't really need to see anything other than that)

Comment: i updated the post with the output of the query. I don't see anything obviously wrong with it, but when i run it in phpmyadmin it returns all of the rows regardless of status, which furthers my suspicion that there's an error i'm not seeing in my query. i'm bad at sql.

Comment: Please be warned that your database queries are widely open for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Comment: Also, try to group the conditions in your `WHERE` clause with brackets. I would assume that currently all rows are returned as the last `AND` condition is only applied to the previous condition for the `issues` column, and not for **all** other columns you search in

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Comment: Where in your query are you expecting it to sort by a specific value?

Answer (score 0):

I feel the issue is in this part of your query,

```
...AND work_orders.status='Awaiting Repair' ORDER BY work_orders.status asc...
```

You are trying to show data's based on a particular value in the status column, then what is the need for ordering it based on the same status field?

Replace the above section with the below and try,

```
  ...AND work_orders.status='Awaiting Repair' ORDER BY work_orders.id asc...
```

The above will order the data's based on the id.